# ASP.NET How to Generate a Student Number with Formula (e.g. RS 1001000)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I need to generate a student number as the formula below with ASP.NET.

So every time a student is added to the database it should automatically generate a student ID.

NOTE( when adding a new student to the database I need to know the last student ID that has been added to the database so it can follow the correct formula).

```
RS 1011000  
RS 1011001  
RS 1011002  
RS 1011003  
RS 1011004
```

Comment: Post the code and let us know where you are facing the challenge.

Comment: Create a SQL procedure which handles the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an id column as bigint identity(10000000, 1) and a calculated column which prefixes 'RS' to that column.

So you would get something like

Create table example (studentId bigint not null identity(10000000, 1),
RsNumber as 'RS' + CAST(studentId as varchar(15)))

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-computed-column-calculated-column-sample.aspx

Comment: Hi, how can i do the syntax in MYSQL. The Application is ASP.net but the database is in MYSQL

Comment: No computed columns on mysql it seems. But you can always add the prefix in the select. The increasing number is done using an auto_value or similar. Let me check.